# "error: constructor Hal9000 in class Hal9000 cannot be applied to given types;"

Tags: java

Hello I am working on an assignment where we are creating a Hal9000. I have created this code:

```
/**
 * Hal9000 simulate an AI that interacts with the crew
 * of a space ship.
 * 
 */
public class Hal9000
{
    private String name;
    /**
     * @return returns the name of the crew member.
     */
    public String getName()
    { return name;
    }
    /**
     * Sets a new crew name @param for the crew member
     */
    public void setName(String newName)
    { String name = newName; 
    }
    /**
     * Hal greets the crew member.
     */
    public String greetCrewMember()
    { return "Welcome," + name;
    }
    /**
     * @return returns a string consisting of "I am sorry,name, I can't + whatToDo"
     * where name is the crew member's name.
     */
    public String doCommand(String whatToDo)
    { return "I am sorry,"+ name + ". I can't" +whatToDo;
    }
}
```

And there is another class that tests the code; I cannot edit this one though when I submit my code into my teacher's code checker.

```
public class Hal9000Tester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Hal9000 hal = new Hal9000("Dave");
        System.out.println(hal.greetCrewMember());
        System.out.println("Expected: Welcome, Dave");
        System.out.println(hal.doCommand("engage drive"));
        System.out.println("Expected: I am sorry, Dave. I can't engage drive");
        hal.setName("Aruna");
        System.out.println(hal.doCommand("power down"));
        System.out.println("Expected: I am sorry, Aruna. I can't power down");
    }
}
```

For the first code I get an error of:
"
/tmp/codecheck/17091723282490386346565379553/submission/Hal9000Tester.java:5: error: constructor Hal9000 in class Hal9000 cannot be applied to given types;

```
    Hal9000 hal = new Hal9000("Dave");
                  ^
```

required: no arguments
  found: String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
"

As I am very new to coding (this is my first course), I am not sure what the issue is and how I can fix it. Thank you for reading, I hope you can help me.

Comment: Just a note, you probably want `return "Welcome, " + name` (a space at the end), not `return "Welcome," + name`. Same with `"I am sorry,"` and `"I can't".

Answer (score 0):

Your class needs a constructor. When `Hal9000Tester` uses `new Hal9000("Dave")` it looks for a method called `Hal9000` in the class `Hal9000` that will take a `String` as its parameter.

By default, a class that does not declare a constructor gets a constructor method added in by the compiler. The added constructor takes no parameters, which is what is causing your error.

You need something like the following:

```
public class Hal9000 {

    // ...

    public Hal9000(String nameOfCrewMember){
        this.setName(nameOfCrewMember);
    }

    // ...

}
```

Also, your `setName` doesn't actually set the name of the crew member. It just creates a local variable.

You need something like:

```
public void setName(String newName){
    this.name = newName;
}
```

Some information on constructors [here] (java docs).(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are attempting to create an instance of an object, but have not set a constructor with the correct parameters yet.

```
public Hal9000(String name)
{
    setName(name);
}
```

This addition would allow your code to run. I would suggest learning more about how Object Oriented Programming works before trying to code too much. The Javadocs have a good resource for this [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/).